# AngularJS: make change when div visible

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a web site based on AngularJS. I'm in the situation where I (via angular) can display or hide a <div> (and it works). Now I need to make substitutions into this <div> but I want that this substitutions start only when the "div" is set visible. This <div> contains user profile so I have thinked to use ".directive" to get a templateUrl and use it for the div's body. But how can I "start" the substitutions like  {{user.name}} ? In the "link" function ? Is it possibile to start the ".directive" functions (load template from url, links, compile, etc etc)  only when the div is set visible ?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

M.

Comment: won't a simple `ng-if` do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not fully understanding the question but ng-show and ng-if seem fit for this purpose...

```
<div ng-show="divisvisible">
    <p ng-if="divisvisible">{{user.name}}</p>
</div>
```